# Overriding a hover event from a library

Tags: javascript, css

Right now, I'm working with a JS library that provides a certain widget.

So essentially I have the list (removed a lot of boilerplate DOM because it's unnecessary to show):

```
<li class="disabled">
```

And when I hover upon this I get:

```
<li class="disabled state-active">
```

I want to override this hover event from adding the 'state-active' class if the class already contains disabled.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through your list items, creating clones of each and replacing the original with the clone. Cloning an element with `cloneNode` does not copy events that are attached to that node:

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(i=0; i<lis.length; i++){
    liClone = lis[i].cloneNode(true);
    lis[i].parentNode.replaceChild(liClone,lis[i]);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/386wxxu8/2/)

**Documentation:**

- [`.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)

Comment: Wouldn't this remove the hover for all li elements, including those without the desired class? Still... tweak it a bit and it is a valid solution.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was very helpful, and I'd need to tweak it like zozo mentioned.